# What if greatest lower bound equals the least upper bound in a set?

Tags: real-analysis

If A is a non empty bounded subset of R, and the g.l.b for A equals the l.u.b for A , what can be said about A?
My answer: A contains precisely one point. Am I right?

I am asked to find an example of a countable bounded subset A of R whose g.l.b and l.u.b. are both in R-A.

I know some countable subsets of R, they are set of positive integers, integers, natural numbers, rationals. But they are not bounded. If I take any open or closed interval in R, they are bounded but not countable. So, any hint or idea is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right: if $A$ contained two or more points, $a, b \in A$ with, say, $a < b$, then $glb(A) \le a < b \le lub(A)$.

Here's a countable, bounded subset of the reals that does not contain its lub or glb:

$$
A = \left\{ - \frac n {n+1} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \left\{ \frac n {n+1} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
$A$ is $\{\dots, -\frac 3 4, -\frac 2 3, -\frac 1 2, 0, \frac 1 2, \frac 2 3, \frac 3 4, \dots \}$. Clearly, $glb(A) = -1$ and $lub(A) = 1$, but neither is a member of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. In fact, it doesn't matter that they're the *greatest* lower bound and *least* upper bound. Using the definition of a lower bound $L$ and an upper bound $U$:

$L \leq x$ for all $x \in A$

$U \geq x$ for all $x \in A$

So if $L = U$, then $L \leq x \leq L$ for all $x \in A$, which means that $x = L = U$ for all $x \in A$.